# Is there an opposite of 'eq' in Lisp?

Tags: if-statement, lisp, equality

I am comparing the first value of two lists, with two outcomes, they are either equal or unequal. My first IF statement is:

```
(if (eq (car L1) (car L2)))
```

Is there an opposite of 'eq' that can I  use?

Like...

```
(if (not eq (car L1) (car L2)))
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: two downvotes, both *after* the formatting was fixed... Why?

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
(not (eq (car L1) (car L2))
```

Comment: @TomStock, what Lisp are you using?

Comment: @TomStock That's pretty ridiculous, but you can create it like this: `(defun not (arg) (if arg nil t))`